# How do I link back to my Rails app from my Ember App? Can I use a Rails url helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js

Is it possible to use a rails helper in a .js.emblem file?

```
li
  ruby:
   link_to(some_path, 'Link Name')
```

Comment: Sorry Zach you can't use a rails helpers in Emblem. There is a Ember helper for link-to http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/links/ I'm sure you have seen. Also it is super easy to make handlebars helpers for ember http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/writing-helpers/.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, I need to link outside of the ember app to the rails app.  Is there a way to determine what environment I'm running in ember (dev vs production)? Then I could conditionally point to localhost/path-to-resource for dev and a hard coded URL for production.

Comment: Are you using the ember-cli, or Ember Rails?

Comment: I'm using Ember Rails

Comment: Is the answer helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a ember rails app add erb to your application.js file `application.js.erb` and add a Environment variable.

```
App.Environment = "<%= Rails.env %>";
```

Then you could make a handlebars helper

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('link-to-rails', function(path, text) {
  var link;
  var development = "http://localhost:3000/";
  var production = "http://yourgreatsite.com/";

  if (App.Environment === 'development') {
    link = new Handlebars.SafeString('<a href=' + development + path + '>' + text + '</a>');
  } else {
    link = new Handlebars.SafeString('<a href=' + production + path + '>' + text + '</a>');
  }

  return link;
});
```

Then you have a handlebars helper you can use like this.

```
{{link-to-rails 'link-to/the-page' 'The Page'}}
```

I hope that helps.
Cheers